# Overload map::key_comp so that I can use map::find on a map of object pointers

Tags: c++, dictionary

`map::find` utilizes `map::key_comp` to search for a key. Default `map::key_comp` is good for built in data types I guess.
I have a map of object pointers `std::map<A*, B*)`, and wish to find for a object pointer of `A`.
Is it possible to overload map::key so that I could use the clean `map::find` semantics? If so, how?
I understand that `std::find_if` may be the one to use, but I just wanted to know if this option is possible.

The other reason I want to overload `map::key_comp` is because, for user created classes, default comparison doesn't have any meaning. So `std::map` is not able to order by keys the way I would have wanted it to (using my logic of object comparison).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at specifying a Compare template argument when you define your map:

```
class CompareIntPtr
{
public:
    bool operator()( int* p1, int* p2 )
    {
        return *p1 < *p2;   
    }
};

int main() {

    typedef std::map< int*, int, CompareIntPtr > TestMapType;
    TestMapType m;

    int *i1 = new int( 1 );
    int *i2 = new int( 2 );

    m.insert( std::make_pair( i1, 1 ) );
    m.insert( std::make_pair( i2, 2 ) );

    TestMapType::const_iterator found = m.find( i1 );
    if( found != m.end() )
        std::cout << "Found i1";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your map with a custom comparer, where you can add your compare logic

```
struct structMyObjectAComparer
    {
        bool operator ()(const A* pLeft, const A* pRight)
        { 

        }
    };

std::map<A*, B*, structMyObjectAComparer> myMap
```